# Minimalistic prototype (js framework)

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, prototype-programming

I want to use the prototype javascript framework for its "class" and inheritance capabilities.  For everything else I will be using jQuery.  Is there a minimalist version of prototype that will give me just this functionality?  I don't want the additional overhead of the entire library if I won't be using it all.

To be specific I want the class and inheritence capabilities that allow me to define classes as follows (examples from wikipedia):

```
var FirstClass = Class.create( {
  // The initialize method serves as a constructor
  initialize: function () {
   this.data = "Hello World";
  }
});
```

and to extend another class:

```
MyNewClass = Class.create( FirstClass, { 
  //Override the initialize method
  initialize: function() { 
    //..
  }, 
  // ...more methods add ... 
});
```

Plus I don't want conflicts between the frameworks (i.e. `$` should *only* be used by jQuery..I only want prototype (or any other suggestion would be fine) for class creation / inheritance).

Comment: Mmm, what class and inheritance capabilities are those exactly? Can you make an example? Because usually, there is a jQuery for anything under the sun.... You are not mixing this up with the JS native `prototype` keyword?

Comment: If you want a nice object oriented framework I would take a look at mootools.

Comment: like I mentioned.  I want to be using jQuery for most functionality.  But jQuery doesn't allow me to nicely define classes (with constructors) which automatically get assigned to a prototype (with the option of extending classes etc.).  I could write my own functionality for this but it seems like it might make more sense to use something well established like the prototype framework

Comment: Ian, personally I think that jQuery is not the best choice fora JS frameworks. Prototype is syntactically better than jQuery and provides the same functionality as jQuery.

Comment: @Max The main reason I would suggest mootools over prototype is that is much closer in performance to jquery and you get that object oriented goodness.  Prototype is pretty slow.

Answer (score 5):

[Inheritance.js](http://code.google.com/p/inheritance/source/browse/trunk/dist/inheritance.js?r=13) was the model that the guys developing the Prototype library have been inspired from and I think it is what you where asking for.

Note: `$super` seems to be `this.parent` as stated in the comments below.

Comment: Wish i could just swap prototype for inheritance.js but it looks like they don't have $super like prototype does.

Comment: not useful, since no $super and reduced functionality.

Comment: @UweHeim from a quick glance it seems it has `this.parent` which to me seems the same as `$super` in Prototype

Comment: Yeah, I didn't check it out, but if you say so, than it should be similar.

Comment: Yes they use this.parent instead of $super. But you can't just swap Prototype.js for Inheritance.js because of that.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for something minimalistic:

```
function clone(obj)  {
    if(typeof obj !== 'undefined') {
        clone.prototype = obj;
        return new clone;
    }
}

function copy(dest, src) {
    for(var name in src) {
        if(src.hasOwnProperty(name))
            dest[name] = src[name];
    }
}

function classof(constructor) {
    return {
        extend : function(base) {
            constructor.prototype = clone(base.prototype);
            return this;
        },

        mixin : function(members) {
            copy(constructor.prototype, members);
            return this;
        }
    };
}
```

Example usage:

```
// base class:
function Foo(value) {
    this.value = value;
}

classof(Foo).mixin({
    inc : function() { ++this.value; }
});

// derived class:
function Bar() {
    Foo.apply(this, arguments);
}

classof(Bar).extend(Foo).mixin({
    dec : function() { --this.value; }
});

var bar = new Bar(42);
bar.inc();
bar.dec();
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't mix Prototype and jQuery. My experience says they don't play nice together. My personal preference would be to use Prototype due to the superior syntactical sugar.

There's no way to disable Prototype's $-function. You can disable jQuery's use of $ via jQuery.noConflict() - but it's not perfect.

As @mhtiza said, use Interitance.js for the class-sugar if you decide to stick to jQuery.

Comment: Ditto for sticking with Prototype. If you only have a need for jQuery then stick with that, but as soon as the larger Prototype is involved then jQuery is outclassed (IMO) and becomes redundant.

Answer (score 1):

For version 1.7.1 I deleted everything below line 1625 in the prototype.js file and I no longer have conflicts with bootstrap and jquery. And the Class.create function still works. The class.create is the only method I wanted as well.

Comment: I did not test everything, but at the first glance, it works like a charm. All of you jquery users, which just are looking for a better class-like support, this could be a viable option.